# UINaviguationBar bottom shadow disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a line of 1px under naviguationbar, but it disappears when I use cancel button of search bar.

Before:
[image]

I press cancel ...

**EDIT Cancel code :**

```
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if(!searchController.searchBar.hidden){
            self.searchController.searchBar.text=""
            self.searchController.searchBar.hidden=true
        }
    }
```

After:
[image]

How can I fix it ? Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Post the code you execute when the cancel button is touched.

Comment: I edited my question, i just hide the searchBar.

Comment: Values of the attributes NavigationBar are equal before and after, so I don't understand why this hair line disappears :(

Comment: The appearance of the navigation bar also depends on your navigation controller configuration. Maybe it would be helpful to see your view / viewcontroller hierarchy?

Comment: It looks like you use a `UISplitViewController` but have a shared navigation bar, which is not the default.. so you're doing some hack to get that navigation bar there, right?

Comment: I didn't use an `UISplitViewController`, and yes I'm doing some hack to get that navigation bar there. I force the frame of search bar :
`searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vueRecherche.frame.width, height: vueRecherche.frame.height)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8.3 fixed the problem. I don't know why.